# Testlink installation failed within xammp in Windows

Tags: testing, testcase, testlink

Today i tried to install Testlink on windows with xammp. path also set as

```
$g_repositoryPath = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/testlink/upload_area';
$tlCfg->log_path = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/testlink/logs';
```

But when i click on "Continue" button after checking the terms check box it gives

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'SCREEN' (T_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Testlink\config.inc.php on line 298
```

In the config.inc.php file code showing as below(mentioned part)

```
/**
 * @var string How to warning user when security weak points exists.
 *
 * 'SCREEN': messages will displayed on login screen, and tl desktop
 * 'FILE': a file with a list is created but users are not notified via GUI
 *         user will receive a message on screen. (default)
 * 'SILENT': same that FILE, but user will not receive message on screen.
 */
$tlCfg->config_check_warning_mode = 'FILE';
```

IS there any way to resolve this?